# Authorize access to Azure using Service Principal

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, openid-connect

I am trying to understand few points about delegating authorization to Azure BLOB using *Azure service principles*.

## How I configure Azure:

- **Create and Configure Service Principal:** in Active Directory I created an application, created a key (password), and set its required permissions to access Azure Storage;
- **Configure IAM of Azure Storage:** under Storage accounts section, I chose my storage account, and under IAM I assigned my account (my login account as XYZ@hotmail.com) to *Storage BLOB Data Contributor* role.

### How I use the configuration in my client App:

1. With the aforementioned configuration; my application takes tenant ID, client ID, client secret, and etc. and sends authorization request to `/authorize` endpoint.
2. Then a window pops-up and asks me to login (using e.g., XYZ@hotmail.com), and then a consent screen pops-up and asks for my permission to allow the service principal to read my Azure storage.
3. After I approve, my client application receives OAuth2.0 `code`.
4. Then I exchange this `code` with an `access_key` via the `/token` endpoint.

Q1: does this `access_key` grant my client application same privileges as XYZ@hotmail.com or service principal?

Using the obtained access key I can read/write azure blob.

Q2: if XYZ@hotmail.com does not have read/write access (i.e., not assigned with the *Storage BLOB Data Contributor* role), my client app would not be able to read/write for the blob, **regardless of the Service Principal's role**. This is where I get confused, I am under the impression that my client App is assuming Service Principal, hence it will have same privileges as the Service Principal, not XYZ@hotmail.com. For instance, XYZ@hotmail.com can have *Contributor* role (i.e., read/write), while the service principle would be assigned with a *Reader* role. In that case, I would have a full access to BLOB storage, while my client app will have only a read access to the BLOB storage. However, it seems client app gets same permissions as XYZ@hotmail.com. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1: does this access_key grant my client application same privileges
> as XYZ@hotmail.com or service principal?

The `access_token` you got has the **delegated permissions which onbehalf of `XYZ@hotmail.com`**. This is because that you used [**Authorization code grant flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code).

> What am I missing here?

For your scenario, I suggest you can use [**client_credentials flow**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) for your app.

**With client_credentials flow, you will get access token only with the application permissions configured in AAD.** Also, this access token is actually onbehalf of your AAD application itself. If you assign a role to your service principal, you will get the access token with the permission of that role.

If you use Authorization code grant flow, you will get the access token onbehalf of the user, not the service principal. So, the access token will have the permission of that user.

Comment: I use the flow the explained here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app which implements, as you mentioned, _authorization code grant flow_. However, I think the _role_ an app assumes in this scenario can have different scopes than the user. So, I read as the following: user registers an app and assign a role to that app which has different scopes than the user; when the app tries to access a BLOB, Azure first asks for the user's consent, and if the user approves, Azure issues tokens for the registered app to assume the role. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not really. the Role is for IAM permissions. You can add delegated permissions of Windows Azure service Managenment API to your app. This is Azure REST API which can let you access resources in your subscription.

Comment: I think you can use IAM to define/assign roles for Azure Storage (e.g., see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#grant-your-registered-app-permissions-to-azure-storage)). Also, in the sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#create-the-block-blob), it seems you can use the access code to delegate access to a service principle.

Comment: Hi @Hamed , Sorry for my late reply. IAM can assign roles to the Applications, but it's really for the client_credentials flow when you call Azure REST Api

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I also started double-checking your suggestion and some tests; and you're right, your initial suggestion is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Hamed ， I'm glad my answer is helpful :-)